# Fail application startup in Spring Boot in case some property is not valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing the problem of finding the best place to put some handling where I can check some of the properties in application.yml and fail app startup of Spring Boot app if they are invalid.

The main point is to find the first place where I can check these properties without running the entire app and fail in the end.

I tried:

- `@EventListener`, but here I was able only to trigger events when the app was started.
- Throwing an exception in `@PostConstruct` in one of my classes with `@Configuration`. I like this one, but it looks like a messy one.

Maybe there are better ways?

Comment: IMHO, if you use some of this parameters to create a certain bean you can check them in  the bean constructors/setters or in Spring factory method for this bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @EventListener, but here I was able only to trigger events when the
>   app was started

There are many different type of events and where you hook in to the startup process depends on the type of event that you listen for.  In your case, consider listening for an `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` if you want to check properties as soon as they are available.